# How to pass options and parameters to eclat algorithm using pyfim?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, apriori, word-frequency

I am new to python and I am trying to generate frequent item sets from a log file using eclat. I am directly calling the eclat function from fim and passing the whole log file as a nested list. I want to use various options while calling eclat, like passing a file directly as input, passing output file name to write the results, min support, max item set size etc. Can someone tell how to pass the arguments to eclat that is being called as a function from fim?
[Attached image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p16zU.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the:

```
eclat(tracts, param_name=value, param_name=value,...)
```

eclat supports several parameters (values displayed are the default one):

```
eclat (tracts, target='s', supp=10, zmin=1, zmax=None, report='a',
       eval='x', agg='x', thresh=10, prune=None, algo='a', mode='',
       border=None)
```

For more informations run in python:

```
help(fim.eclat)
```